# simple text in android chipview

Tags: android, android-chips

I'm using this [chipView](https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips) in android for [this simple tag](https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html#chips-usage) like view. But it only accepting email-id's and not the simple text tags.

```
Contact contact = new Contact(firstName, lastName, displayName, @NonNull emailAddress, Uri avatarUrl)
```

If i press Enter in the chipView, it takes only email as tags, and erasing simple text from view

Answer (score 0):

Seems like chips library you are using is accepts only email.
Use this [MaterialChips](https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput)  library.

Here is the snippet :

```
chipsInput.addChip(ChipInterface chip);
// or
chipsInput.addChip(Object id, Drawable icon, String label, String info);
// or
chipsInput.addChip(Drawable icon, String label, String info);
// or
chipsInput.addChip(Object id, Uri iconUri, String label, String info);
// or
chipsInput.addChip(Uri iconUri, String label, String info);
// or
chipsInput.addChip(String label, String info);
```

Comment: It is showing the following error

    **Error:Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':app:_debugAnnotationProcessor' after it has been resolved.** when trying to add dependency in build.gradle @akshay_shahane

Comment: I resolved the above error, but how to disable cursor in **ChipsInput** xml (view)? Because whenever activity launches where is have this **ChipsInput** keyboard becomes visible automatically because of the ChipsInput View in that layout. So i wonder how to disable cursor (ultimately type option in this <ChipsInput> xml tag view.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" add this line in manifest for activity

Comment: Now the keyboard is not popping on activity launch. Thanks a lot bro. But the cursor blinks at last position of the elements in the **ChipsItem** view. how to remove cursor blinking inside the **ChipsItem** view. I definitely accept the answer, can you help out the above case please!

Comment: i think you cant do that its an open issue for this library https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput/issues/44